# How to save an Object to Mongo db using reactive

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I have a springboot project with the spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive dependency. I have the following code which I use to save a student object in the collection:

```
@Autowired
private ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;

public Mono<Student> save(String studentDetails) throws IOException {

Student student = mapper.readValue(studentDetails, Student.class);

Mono<Student> studentMono = reactiveMongoTemplate.save(student, "StudentCollection");

return studentMono;

}
```

I have configured the mongo client. The code above persists data in the collection only when I block the stream. How can I fix this?

UPDATE

My mongo client has a custom configuration as shown below:

```
public class MongoConfig {

@Autowired
private MongoSslContext mongoSslContext;


@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {

        mycustomSslContext = mongoSslContext.createSSLContext();


        SslSettings sslSettings = SslSettings.builder().context(mycustomSslContext).build();

        MongoClientSettings.builder().sslSettings(sslSettings);

        return MongoClients.create(new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27019/studentDB?streamType=netty&ssl=true&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509"));       
}

public ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory() throws UnrecoverableKeyException,
        KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {        

    return new SimpleReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory(mongoClient(), "studentDB");

}

@Bean
public ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate() throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException,
        KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {

    return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory());
}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet showing how/where you intend to use this method? Is this a Spring WebFlux app? A Spring MVC app? Something else?

Comment: Use flatMap, check my answer will help you to solve

Comment: Above method is within the class StudentService. This method is triggered by calling studentService.save(payload) @BrianClozel

Answer (score 0):

Use `FlatMap`, this is how you can use reactive..

```
public Mono<Student> save(String studentDetails) throws IOException {

    Student student = mapper.readValue(studentDetails, Student.class);
    Mono<Student> studentMono = reactiveMongoTemplate.save(student);

    return studentMono;

}
```

Comment: It is not possible to call flatMap in this case as student is not a stream. Also I need to pass in the collection name to the reactiveMongoTemplate.  I am not using the repository interface and using reactiveMongoTemplate directly as I need to do lower level transactions

Comment: is it simple mongoClient or you configured it??

Comment: sorry got it, just checked your dependency

Comment: I just used Mono<Student> studentMono = reactiveMongoTemplate.save(student) and worked fine for me, do we need to pass Collection??.

Comment: it's with custom configuration and yes, I need to pass the collection name to save the object to.

Comment: can you please add it if possible.

Comment: I have added my custom configuration. MongoSslContext class creates an ssl context using the key store and trust store and that's the ssl settings used by the MongoClient. @kj007

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180517/discussion-between-kj007-and-bluestar).